# Image not loading

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

So, I have an upload functionality that results in an image being uploaded. Sometimes (about 50% of the time) after the image is uploaded, the default image displays and the onError method is called. However, the resulting event doesn't give any insights into what went wrong.

The display code is this

```
renderImage(){
  const { photos, photoDir, onShowPhotoModal } = this.props;

  const item = photos.get(0);

  return (
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={onShowPhotoModal}>
            <Image
                defaultSource={require('../../styles/images/default-post-image.png')}
                resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.cover}
                style={[styles.cardContentPhoto, localStyle.photo]}
                source={{uri : this.state.imageUrl}}
                onError={this.tryOneMoreTime}
            />
        </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}

render() {
    const { loadNow, photos, onShowPhotoModal } = this.props;
    const { index } = this.state;

    if(photos.size === 0)
      return null;

    return (
        <View>
            <View style={localStyle.container}>
                {this.renderImage()}
            </View>
            <CirclesIndicator length={photos.size} activeIndex={index}/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

[image]

If I open the image in a modal and then return, it displays correctly, but if I try to load the same image and force a re-render a few seconds after the error event is called, with a randomized url, it still doesn't appear.

```
tryOneMoreTime(evt){

    const { photos, photoDir, onShowPhotoModal } = this.props;

    dbg(`Something went wrong loading image ${photoDir}/main_${photos.get(0).filename}`, evt);

    if(this.state.tries === 0)

        setTimeout(() =>
            this.setState({
                tries : 1,
                imageUrl : utils.photoUrl(photoDir, photos.get(0).filename, 'main', true)
            }), 2000);
}
```

Tested on iOS Simulator, RN 0.38.1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, yeah the error can be accessed through evt.nativeEvent.error

Comment: Are you sure? For me nativeEvent.error is always undefined. What were reasons it was not loading? I have image that is not loading and i dont know why.